# Why isn't code for $op == 'presave' being executed in hook_nodeapi?

Tags: 6, nodes, hooks

I want the administrator users can publish nodes of the story content type; the other roles can unpublish. The following is the code I am using, but it doesn't work. I unchecked the box "published", which is in the "story" content type.

```
   function mymodulename_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) { 
     global $user; 

     if ($op== 'presave' && $node->type == 'story') { 
       if (in_array('administrator',array_values($user->roles))) { 
         $node->status = 1;
       }
     }
   }
```

I am using `echo 'test'` above on the `if ($op....)`, the page outputs "test." When I put the `echo 'test'` into `if` body, the page doesn't output "test." but When I delete `$op == 'presave'`， it can output "test."

Comment: Use `dpm()` from the devel module and `dpm($user)`.
You can also add a `dpm($op)` just after the `global $user` to see which operations are executed.

Comment: Passing `$user->roles` to `array_values()` is not necessary; `$user->roles` can be passed directly to `in_array()`.

Comment: Drupol, the global $user can be execusted, because When I put the echo 'test' into if body, the page doesn't output "test." but When I delete $op == 'presave'， it can output "test."

Comment: kiamlaluno,why i couldn't by means of the hook_nodeapi to change the publish status?thank you

Comment: Generally it's not a good practice to directly refer to a role from code that manage user rights. Instead you should check for a specific permission and grant this permission to user with this role.

Comment: could you tell me how to do that? thank you.

Comment: It's enough you use `user_access('permission to check')`.

Comment: @enjoylife Do you actually have a role called 'administrator'?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your problem, you're editing the node right ? Because `presave` acts during saving.

On a site I use this module which is quite handy, maybe it can help you: [Publish Content](http://drupal.org/project/publishcontent)